# Looking for a 1-form that integrates to 1 over the manifold $S^1$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, pullback

Let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2:z= 0\}$ and $f:A\rightarrow S^1$ with  $(x,y,z)\mapsto(-y(1-z^2),x(1-z^2))$.

I am looking for a $\omega$ s.t. for  we get $\int_{S^1}\omega=1$ and $\int_{A}F^*\omega=1$.

> Which $\omega$ can I take?

I tried $\omega=xdx$ but that does not give $\int_{S^1}\omega=1$.

Comment: Your map doesn't land on $S^1$, but on $D^1$, the unit disk. For example, if $z=1,x=y=0$, then $(0,0,z)\to (0,0)$.

Comment: If $S^1 = \{(u,v) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid u^2 + v^2 = 1\}$, then your $f$ does not take values in $S^1$. For instance, $f(0,0,1) = (0,0)$. So, what do you understand by $S^1$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks for the tip

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for the tip

Comment: It should have been z=0

Comment: @WallaceWest: Should I understand that, since $z=0$, the function is $f(x,y,0) = (-y,x)$?

Comment: @AlexM. Now that you say so, that does seem to be the case :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $f\big|_A \big( (x , y, 0) \big) = (-y, x)$, therefore $f \big| _A$ is clearly a diffeomorphism, so as soon as we find $\omega$ on $S^1$ such that $\int _{S^1} \omega = 1$ it will automatically follow that $\int _A f^* \omega = \int _{f(A)} \omega = \int _{S^1} \omega$ (without the need for you to require this).

Now endow $S^1$ with the form $\omega = \frac 1 {2\pi} (x \ \Bbb d y - y \ \Bbb d x)$. Notice that, using any of the techniques shown in [the answers to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028915/integral-over-the-manifold-s1) (I am going to use Stokes' theorem with $S^1 = \partial D_1$), the integral of this form is

$$\int \limits _{\partial D_1} \omega = \frac 1 {2\pi} \int \limits _{D_1} \Bbb d (x \ \Bbb d y - y \ \Bbb d x) = \frac 1 {2\pi} \int \limits _{D_1} 2 \ \Bbb d x \wedge \Bbb d y = \frac 1 \pi \int \limits _{D_1} \Bbb d x \Bbb d y = \frac 1 \pi \text{ area } (D_1) = 1 ,$$

therefore it is a form as required. This form is not unique though, there are infinitely many that integrate to $1$.